# A linear recurrence relation with no primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Let $r(m) = m^2 + m -1$ and $q(m) =(r(m) +2)^2 - 2$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

For a particular $m$,
let $A_1=m^3+2m^2 +2m$

$ A_2 = q(m) A_1 + r(m) $

$A_n = q(m) A_{n-1}-A_{n-2}+r(m)$

It appears $A_n$ is always composite for all positive integers $m$ and $n$ except when $m=1$ and $n=1$ in which case $A_1=5$ is prime.

Is this observation true?

My attempt: For a particular $m$, we have

$A_1 \equiv 0 $ (mod $m$)

$A_2 \equiv - 1$ (mod $m$)

$A_3 \equiv 0 $ (mod $m$)

$A_4 \equiv 0 $ (mod $m$)

$A_5 \equiv - 1$ (mod $m$)

By induction, it can be shown that $A_n \equiv - 1$ (mod $m$) if $n \equiv 2 (\ $ mod $3$) and  $A_n \equiv 0 $ (mod $m$) if $n \not\equiv 2 (\ $ mod $3$)

If $m>1$ and $n \not\equiv 2 (\ $ mod $3$) ,  $A_n$ is composite because $m \ | \ A_n$. The remaining cases to prove are $m=1$ and $n \equiv 2 (\ $ mod $3$)

NB: All terms of the sequence $A_n$ appear to be positive integer  solutions in $z$ to the diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=z^4+z^3 +z^2 +z+1$. More on this Diophantine equation https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403542/positive-integer-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-z4z3-z/404278#404278

I found out a paper that considers a more general equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=z^4+c_1z^3 +c_2z^2 +c_3z+1$ where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are known integers. https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042117500129.  However, it uses Mathematics  am not familiar with. Also am more interested in the case when $z$ is prime. The paper provides an algorithm for constructing all solutions $x, y, z$ to the more general equation but does not discuss the primality of solutions in $z$. If the claim about $A_n$ is true, then to test $n = p^4 +p^3 +p^2 +p+1$, $p$ prime, for primality, one simply checks if $n$ passes the Fermat test and if $b^{(n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1$ ( mod  $n$)  for some base $b$
https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02327  ( General purpose promality test - Theorem 2.2)

Comment: The claim is verified for $A_n<10^7$

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained where those particular values for $q(m)$ and $r(m)$ come from ? Unless it's some Ramanujan-type inspiration

Comment: Check out this link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403542/positive-integer-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-z4z3-z/404278#404278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a full solution. I prefer to put it as a separate answer here since
the method is somewhat different. As explained in the OP, we may assume $m=1$ ; then $A_n$ reduces to the sequence $a_n$ defined by $a_1=5,a_2=36$ and $a_n=7a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+1$ for $n\geq 2$.

Now, consider the Fibonacci-type sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 2}$ defined by

$$
f_2=3,f_3=4,f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2} (n\geq 4)
$$

and the complementary sequence $(g_n)_{n\geq 2}$ defined by

$$
g_2=12,g_3=62,g_4=243,g_5=1060,
$$

$$
g_n=3g_{n-1}+6g_{n-2}-3g_{n-3}-g_{n-4} (n\geq 6)
$$

Using the usual linear recurrence machinery, we see that $f_n$ is a linear combination of powers of the roots of $F=X^2-X-1$, and $g_n$ is a linear combination of powers of the roots of $G=X^4-3X^3-6X^2+3X+1=(X^2+X-1)(X^2-4X-1)$.

It follows that $h_n=f_ng_n$ is a linear combination of powers of the roots of $H$, the polynomials whose roots are exactly the product of one root of $F$ by one root of $G$. Using PARI-GP, I computed that $H=(X-1)^2(X^2-7X+1)(X^2+3X+1)$.

Now, because $X-1$ and $X^2-7X+1$ are factors of $H$, we see that $a_n$ satisfies the linear recurrence defined by $H$. One can check by hand that $a_n=h_n$ for $2\leq n \leq 9$ ; we deduce that this identity is satisfied for all $n$ because of the linear recurrence.

Conclusion : $a_n=f_ng_n$ for $n\geq 2$ with $f_n\geq 3$, so $a_n$ is composite.

Comment: just wondering how you found the two recurrence relations $f_n$ and $g_n$ such that $a_n=f_n\cdot g_n$. I would like to show that a similar sequence $b_n$ defined as $b_1= 10,  b_2 = 70,  b_n= 7b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}+1$ contains no primes.

Comment: @DavidJones I found them as follows. It suffices to find $f_n$ since $g_n$ is just $\frac{a_n}{f_n}$. Now $f_1$ must be an integer dividing $a_1$, so there are only finitely many possible values for it. Similarly for $f_2,f_3,f_4$. Also, a sequence satisfying a linear recurrence of order $2$ is uniquely defined (except in exceptional degenerate cases) by its first four terms. So we are left with a finite number of cases to test.

Comment: Turns out $a_n$ can also be expressed as a $a_n=f_ng_n$ where $f_1=1, f_2=3, g_1=5,  g_2= 12$ and $f_n = 3f_{n-1} - f_{n-2}$, $g_n = 3g_{n-1} - g_{n-2}$ $n\ge 3$

Comment: Same definition for $b_n$ except a change of initial values $f_1=2, f_2=5, g_1=5, g_2=14$

Comment: That means $x=5$ is the only prime $x$ such that $P(x) = x^4+x^3 +x^2+x+1$ is composite and $P(x) $ has a positive divisor congruent to 1 modulo $x$, assuming the solutions given here are complete https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403542/positive-integer-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-z4z3-z

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.

For $n\equiv 0 \ \textrm{or} \ 2 (\mod{3})$, it is easy to see by induction that $A_n$ is divisible by $m+1$.

So we are left with the case $m=1$ and $n\equiv 1 (\mod{3})$.
By induction, when $n\equiv 4 (\mod{6})$, $A_n$ is divisible by $m^2+m+1$.

So we are left with the case $m=1$ and $n\equiv 1 (\mod{6})$.

This subcase seems interesting and non-trivial as the degree of the factors of $A_{6k+1}$ seems to grow with $k$. So, it would seem that there is a non-trivial recurrent sequence $B_k$ dividing $A_{6k+1}$.

UPDATE : By induction, when $n\equiv 25 (\mod{30})$, $A_n$ is divisible by $m^4 + 2m^3 + 2m^2 + m - 1$.

So we are left with the case $m=1$ and $n\equiv 1,7,13 \ \textrm{or} \ 19 (\mod{30})$.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see $A_{n-2}$ in the third row.